# Reserving and deleting vectors?

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector

I'm having a problem deleting data of a vector.

When I create the data, I first reserve space in an array, and then resize the vector and copy the addresses of the array:

```
//Create the vertices
verts.reserve(vn); verts.resize(vn);
TriVertex *vertsaux = new TriVertex[vn];

for(int i=0, c=0; i<vn; i++, c+=3)
{
     vertsaux[i].SetId(i);
     vertsaux[i].SetCoords0(Vector3(vs[c], vs[c+1], vs[c+2]));

     //Inicializate texture vertices
     vertsaux[i].SetTextureCoords(Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f));
}

for(int i=0; i<vn; i++)
{
     verts[i] = &vertsaux[i];
}
```

But in the destructor of my class, it gives me a runtime error when I do this:

```
for (i=0; i < this->verts.size(); i++) {
     delete this->verts[i];
}
```

Anybody know why can this is happening?

By the way, I can't just create `new TriVertex` inside the `for`, because of some implementation details...

Comment: What does your declaration of verts look like?  Is it vector<TriVertex> or vector<TriVertex*>?

Comment: `verts.reserve(vn); verts.resize(vn);` is redundant. All vector operations that grow the vector will do the reserve for you. You use `.reserve(N)` only when you'd grow the vector incrementally, know a minimum final size, and don't want the intermediate reservations.

Comment: You do not need to use `this->` to refer to members of your own class.

Answer (score 3):

You allocate an array of objects with

```
TriVertex *vertsaux = new TriVertex[vn];
```

To delete that again you need to do

```
delete[] vertsaux;
```

You can not delete the elements individually.

Answer (score 1):

You're not really giving us enough information.  What it the
type of `verts`?  And why are you using `versaux`?  From what
little I can see, the most logical solution would be to have
`std::vector <TriVertex> verts;` as a class member, and
initialize it directly, without the intermediate dynamic
allocations.  Maybe:

```
verts.reserve(vn);

for ( int i = 0; i < vn; ++ i ) {
    verts.push_back( TriVertex() );
    TriVertex& current = verts.back();
    current.SetId( i );
    current.SetCoords( Vector3( *vs, *(vs+1), *(vs+ 2) ) );

    current.SetTextureCoords( Vector2( 0.0, 0.0 ) );
    vs += 3;
}
```

I don't see any reason for the intermediate, dynamically
allocated array.  (If there is, Joe's response is correct.)

Comment: In `C++11` you can use `std::vector::emplace_back()`, which directly creates the object in the `vector`. This erodes the need for manual memory management even more.

Comment: @tillaert I don't see where it changes much with regards to the need for manual memory management.  For that matter, in this particular case, I suspect that move constructors and various other legal optimizations mean that `emplace_back` won't make much of a difference.  (In other cases, of course...)

Comment: I didn't mean it towards your example, your code is fine.  Some coders are very picky on optimizations, and tend to use vectors of pointers to achieve this goal. I wanted to point out that `emplace` and move-semantics erode this case. I am sorry if my comment caused confusion.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete this->verts[i];
```

This deletes one item inside the dynamically allocated array you created and is actually UB to delete it that way.

An array like that should be deleted with `delete[]` statement, and that deletes the **entire array**.

Comment: But verts is a STL vector. Do I have to do that with vectors too?

Comment: this->verts[i]; deletes an item in the array you placed inside verts, not verts itself

Answer (score 0):

Since you create an array of `TriVertex`, pointed to by `vertsaux`, then you should delete the array using:

```
delete[] vertsaux;
```

You can't delete the individual elements of the array.

Having done the above `delete[]`, you should remove all the elements of `verts` like this:

```
verts.clear();
```

This is because since you have deleted `vertsaux`, the pointers inside `verts` are invalid.

*I'm assuming that verts is something like: `std::vector<TriVertex*>`*

Comment: Ok. So is it correct if I do this?: delete [] verts[0];
Or is there memory that is not being deleted?

Comment: @Sara: I don't think that you *should* do the `delete[] verts[0]`, just for the sake of consistency.

Answer (score 0):

When you allocate an array using

```
TriVertex *vertsaux = new TriVertex[vn];
```

you have to deallocate using `delete[]` by calling

```
delete[] vertsaux;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things here:

1. As a number of people have pointed out, allocating an array requires deleting as an array.  However, I think it's masking what you're really trying to do here.  Change your allocation to do a "`new TriVertex`" for each item.
2. Assuming your vector is storing `TriVertex*` pointers, you indeed have to delete each item in your destructor (as you have written.)

Thus, fixing your initial allocation strategy for `TriVertex` objects should solve the problem.

```
for(int i=0, c=0; i<vn; i++, c+=3)
{
    TriVertex *vertsaux = new TriVertex;

    vertsaux->SetId(i);
    vertsaux->SetCoords0(Vector3(vs[c], vs[c+1], vs[c+2]));

    //Initializing texture vertices
    vertsaux->SetTextureCoords(Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f));
    verts[i] = vertsaux;
}
```